# Where to store large amounts of images for my site?

Tags: image, store

If i would want to deploy a site, like ebay, where people will be able to sell something, i would need to store large amounts of images, like many thausends of them and i would need to display about 30 images on some pages.

**Normaly i would make a separate server and store them in there, but what else can i do ?**

I was trying to store my images on some image hosts like ImageShack, but i have noticed that if i try to request 30 images at same time, some of the images are not showing, looks like imageshack dosnt like to be used this way.

Still there must be some other ways to do it, maybe cloud servers, or other services like imageshack. Does anyone have experience with this ? what would be the best practice beside having a second server ?

Comment: your question doesn't fit to stackoverflow . see [What can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: belongs to webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Have a file server served by a HTTPD server (e.g. Apache HTTPD) for these static contents.

You can store into the DBMS file locations of the static contents instead of saving as a BLOB this way.

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting traffic, you can store all images (even static files like CSS) in a separate server , like http://staticimg.yourdomain.com . With this way, your web server will be less busy serving download requests.